# Javascript function not working despite no errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and I am working on a simple function. I am trying to get a button to redirect to another webpage on click, and I am attempting to implement it through javascript/jquery. Although I get no errors in the console, the functions simply don't fire for some reason. I have also utilized an alert to test, and even the alert does not come up. Any help is appreciated. All files are correctly linked to the HTML document. The commented out code was my javascript attempt and that did not work either.

```js
//document.getElementById("updateB").onclick = function() {updateButton()};
 $("#updateB").click(function() {
 updateButton()});


function updateButton() {
alert("Working");
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}

function deleteButton() {
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><button class ="buttonUpdate" id="updateB">Update</button></td>
<td><button class="buttonDelete">Delete</button></td>
```

I'm loading the scripts like this:

```html
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: not sure about location.href but usually I use window.open("url")

Comment: Thanks but the function still does not fire.

Comment: can you show your button html?

Comment: button html is now added in the question.

Comment: You have `//` before `document.getElementById` in your code. Is that what it actually looks like on your site? If so, you're commenting out that line. Also, you have two click event handlers. One is vanilla JS and the other is jQuery?

Comment: I edited your question and It's actually working.

Comment: He has comment because he has thew same with jquery afterwards

Comment: Your code works for me. The only reason can be that js is not included correctly. Can you please show the code where you are including jquery and javascript?

Comment: https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/YzPRjeX this works

Comment: Only thing i can imagine is that you should define the button func first but if that were the case you would get an error.

Comment: Code has been edited to display jquery and javascript script.

Comment: in your devTools network tab, is those two files being correctly loaded?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Yes, both files are seen in the network tab with no errors.

Comment: Try these things: 1) Double check that your .js files are in the same folder of the directory as you index.html, and if that looks good, 2) if you have other things going on in your index.js file besides what is in the example above, extract the portion of the script you have in your example from your index.js file, place it in a separate script element or file located before the index.js and after jquery.js, and try running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should run the index.js inside the document ready function, button event listener would be added when the button is actually available. Until the dom is ready to button will not be available for the binding.

try adding a dom ready function and add your binding and other logic inside it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#updateB").click(function() {
       updateButton()});
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but strangely enough I thought I tried this earlier and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code once onload is emitted. You can learn about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

```js
window.onload = () => {
  console.log('your code should be run in this function');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to work with the DOM you have to make sure the DOM is ready by using JQuery's Document Ready function.

```js
$(function(){
   //document.getElementById("updateB").onclick = function()    {updateButton()};
   $("#updateB").click(function() {
      updateButton()
   });
});


function updateButton() {
   alert("Working");
   window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}

function deleteButton() {
   window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><button class ="buttonUpdate" id="updateB">Update</button></td>
<td><button class="buttonDelete">Delete</button></td>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code runs properly. Only pay attention that, you have a commented code in the beginning.

The button event is triggered, the only reason the page is not redirecting to the w3schools, is because the browser is blocking such action.

Please see the snippet working below:

```js
function updateButton() {
  alert("Working");
  window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
}

document.getElementById("updateB").onclick = function() {     updateButton();
};
```

```html
<td>
<button class ="buttonUpdate" id="updateB">Update</button>
</td>
<td>
<button class="buttonDelete">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @calamity, please check it and let us know in case we can clarify anything else.

Comment: The issue was not with my browser, thanks though.